# Android SQLite: How to generate big table for testing purpose?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am testing the capabilities of the device -- to show the customer the size of data that can be stored inside the device, how fast it can be retrieved, how fast the search works, etc.

I am using my content provider to access the `product` database table with few columns. I have already moved the code to the content provider to avoid the extra communication when inserting the test records. The following code is called via menu from an activity to fill the table with the test content

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(DemoContentProvider.PRODUCTS_CONTENT_URI + "/insertdemo");
getContentResolver().insert(uri, null);
```

The URI is recognized in the `.insert` method of the content provider and the following private method (of the same content provider) is called to fill the table (notice the 100 thousands of items):

```
private void insertDemoProducts() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; ++i) {
        String id = Integer.toString(i);
        insertProduct(id, "Test product " + id, "100", "75.50", "70.27");
    }
}
```

The inner `insertProduct()` looks like that:

```
private void insertProduct(String code, String name, String stock,
                           String price,  String listprice) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(ProductTable.COLUMN_CODE, code);
    values.put(ProductTable.COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(ProductTable.COLUMN_STOCK, stock);
    values.put(ProductTable.COLUMN_PRICE, price);
    values.put(ProductTable.COLUMN_LISTPRICE, listprice);

    sqlDB.insert(ProductTable.TABLE_PRODUCT, null, values);
}
```

It works, but it takes *"forever"*. How can I make it faster? What is the fastest method you know to fill the table?

Just some numbers to consider: 1000 items takes about 20 seconds to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use transactions when writing to a sqlite-database, otherwise it will persist the data for every insert i.e save it to sd which will take "forever".

for instance, make insertProduct take a list of products and save them in one transaction:

```
private void insertProducts(List<Product> products) {
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        for(Product product : products) {
            insertProduct(...);
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

This is how you can implement it in your existing code:

```
private void insertDemoProducts() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        sqlDB.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; ++i) {
            String id = Integer.toString(i);
            insertProduct(id, "Test product " + id, "100", "75.50", "70.27");
        }
        sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        sqlDB.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot test it now, but how the extra functionality (the transaction) can make things faster? Can you point me to any documentation that explains the reason?

Comment: The beginTransaction-method will tell the database that you are about to start a transaction, and that it does not need to write anything to sd until the endTransaction-method is run. It then evaluates if the change to the database was successful, in which case it writes all the changes at once, or if it is not successful, i.e the setTransactionSuccessful has not been run it makes a rollback. You can read more on [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) in the documentation

Comment: I hope I understand the mechanism of transactions. However, when using transactions, the insertion to db must be done anyway. Moreover, the extra data structures must be created to implement the transaction mechanism. Then, why the simple `insert` without transaction is more complex than `insert` plus transaction?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. You need to wrap the insert-method with a transaction. How you do it is up to you, the extra data structures are not necessary, you can start the transaction in insertDemoProducts before your for-loop, but then you need to expose the SQLiteDatabase in that layer. The solution to your problem is to use transactions. I have supplied some example-code in how this can be done.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include example of how you can do it with existing code.

Comment: Thanks, +1. I do not know exactly why the *without transaction* is slower than *with transaction*, but it is so. Possibly, a simple *insert* uses also one transaction internally, and the outer transaction replaces the internal one.

Comment: Adding a transaction makes it faster because inserts within a transaction occur only in-ram until the transaction is committed (at which point they all transfer to storage), while inserts outside of a transaction occur directly in-storage.  Storage is massively slower than RAM when writing.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I am not completely satisfied with the accepted question because I do not understand the reason why adding the transaction makes it faster.

Looking at the Android sources, I have found that the `sqlDB.insert(...)` calls `insertWithOnConflict(...)` and that one construct the string for the SQL command using the `StringBuilder` class (with questionmarks as placeholders for the inserted values). Only then the string is passed to the `SQLiteStatement` constructor together with array of the inserted values. This means that string with the SQL command is being built again and again.

Further, a string representation of an SQL command template can be precompiled thus avoiding also the repeated compilation of the command. Then `.bindXxx` and `.execute` methods can be used for inserting the wanted records into the table. When put together, I did use the followig code (iside the outer transaction as [Dean suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775322/1346705)):

```
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT INTO ");
        sql.append(ProductTable.TABLENAME);
        sql.append("(");
        sql.append(ProductTable.COLUMN_CODE);
        sql.append(",");
        sql.append(ProductTable.COLUMN_NAME);
        sql.append(",");
        sql.append(ProductTable.COLUMN_STOCK);
        sql.append(",");
        sql.append(ProductTable.COLUMN_PRICE);
        sql.append(",");
        sql.append(ProductTable.COLUMN_LISTPRICE);
        sql.append(") VALUES (?, ?, 100, 75.50, 70.27)");

        SQLiteStatement insert = sqldb.compileStatement(sql.toString());

        for (int i = 1; i <= 300000; ++i) {
            insert.bindLong(1, i);
            insert.bindString(2, "Test product " + i);
            insert.execute();
        }
```

When compared with adding the transaction only, the result is about 3-times faster. The 300 thousands records were inserted in about 3 minutes and 15 seconds on Nexus 7.