# Android: Building big demo table... How to cancel the process when needed?

Tags: android

For demonstration purpose, I want to build rather large SQLite table of products. I do have two menu items in the main screen activity -- one for clearing the table, and the other for filling it with demo items. To show the capability of the device to the customer, I am inserting 300 thousands records, and it takes slightly more than 3 minutes.

The data is generated inside the content provider, using special URI for insertion. When invoked, the following code is active in the content provider.

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String path;
    long id = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
        ...        
    case PRODUCTS_INSERT_DEMO_DATA:
        insertDemoProducts();
        ...
        break;
    }
```

The `insertDemoProduct()` implementation is shown in [the separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16775061/1346705). Basically, it runs in the same thread. Because of that, the application does not respond during the mentioned 3+ minutes. I can generate it in advance, before showing it to the customer. Anyway, I would like to learn how to implement it so that I was able to see the progress and to be able to stop it earlier.

**Update:** I am going to implement the mechanism that gets the data from a web service. This way, I prefer the solution that may look too complex for that task (filling the data in the loop), but that would be a testbed for the future functionality.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to see the progress, you need to run your function in a separate thread, otherwise the UI thread is too busy to show anything. You can use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

To cancel it when needed, use the cancel mechanism of the AsyncTask. Basically, your will have to check regularly whether you are supposed to stop working, and exit your task if requested. All the information you need is in the AsyncTask documentation.

Comment: Thanks, +1. The doc says `AsyncTask` *... should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most)*, but it also says what should be used for longer tasks. Anyway, see the update.